# Unable to get cronjob running in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I am using whenever gem to schedule a small cron job.

Here is my schedule.rb

```
every 1.minute do 
    rake "send_query:to_dummy", :environment => "development"
end
```

Here is the rake task

```
namespace :send_query do    

    task :to_dummy => :environment do 
        Dummy.create(name: "1234")
    end 

end
```

The rake task  `rake send_query:to_dummy` works fine in itself. But I can't get the cronjob working

when I type whenever

```
 whenever
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/gvpmahesh/code/digifutura/website && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake send_query:to_admins --silent'

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/gvpmahesh/code/digifutura/website && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake send_query:to_dummy --silent'

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

I have tried `whenever -i` and `sudo service cron restart` still the cronjob is not executing. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: is this cronjob working with some other time pattern?

Comment: Yes the same pattern is working with some other app

Comment: Take a look into the cron logfile. There you should find a hint what's going wrong. Maybe cron can't find your Ruby or some thing else is missing e.g. an environment variable for an external service like your database.

Comment: If you read `whenever` output, it says it didn't update your crontab file. Cron will thus not pick this up and never run these commands. Also, why would you want to run cronjobs in development??

Comment: Run `crontab -l` and check if it shows the cronjobs which `whenever` shows after running its command.